# GeneXus 15 - live editting (DUDA)

Tags: genexus

Estamos generando una aplicación en GeneXus 15 para Smart Devices y en su momento necesitábamos configurar el *layout* de las pantallas de la aplicación a través de *live editting*.

Laa dudas son las la siguientes:

1. Hemos generado un apk en modo *release* pero cuando lo probamos este sigue mostrando el mensaje, se está tratando de conectar con *live editing* lo cual no es correcto.
2. Cuando se vaya a publicar en el Playstore, ¿qué configuración es necesaria para que este mensaje de conexión no siga apareciendo, provocando molestias en nuestros usuarios?

Espero puedan ayudarnos ya que estamos en fase de liberación y necesitamos resolver esta duda.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para desactivar el modo **Live Editing** alcanza con cambiar el valor del *combo* **Configuration** de **Live Editing** a **Release** y volver a generar la aplicación.

Mientras el modo **Live Editing** esté activado, no importa que estés ejecutando desde GeneXus o usando el .apk, siempre va a intentar contectarse al servidor.

Puedes [ver la documentación de Live Editing](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27806,Live%20Editing%20in%20Smart%20Devices%20applications,) (en inglés).

Si ya cambiaron a **Release** y sigue apareciendo el mensaje, te sugiero que prueben hacer un **Rebuild All** en la base de conocimiento. Si aún así sigue apareciendo, deberías contactar a Soporte de GeneXus porque habría que analizar bien el caso.